# Decrypting hyperlocal with HMAC-SHA1

Tags: java, encryption

Looking through Google's RTB documentation, I've been trying to decrypt the hyperlocal string that I get (currently using the sample string in the documentation to test: https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-hyperlocal).

In the first attempt that I made, I keep on getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (The AdxBidRequestDecryptor class).

In the second attempt (based on Google's own code), I get output like this after failing verification: �qT����p�R����<��h�7�$�Ci��,H�}�x����K�:&쯄��lk'<��zN?�垒}��i�AsX�S����\b�x��vV'P���!~K�W�h��@g٫Mim5ŗ�P����g-+S�m�l��Hϯc��ՠ�&Qx'{\\5\f��>�\tP\nvd�q;P�b�<��d_�e���)�F�&�MWn�Sd�~Jz_�4�Ƕ�Fp5��7u��ӴM����v$��3��g�fq��

Google's RTB documentation isn't rather clear on what exactly is in that string and their decryptor [sample code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j12du6jzebpwrwx/64bitdecrypter-v2.0.1.tgz) mostly based on C++ code and Java code that seems to only validate a signature in it.

I'm not exactly sure if the [original code (contains my own version and a modified Google version with my own changes)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6js6vjg284vdi2c/Archive.zip) simply requires a few adjustments or if my implementation is simply flawed at the core.

Comment: OK, so you pass the verify part (step 3) of the decryption? Could you show what you get if you hex encode the output? It's not likely that it shows anything useful as a String.

Comment: I don't pass the verify part when I put in the test key (I pass it in main as a test). However I do simply pass in a dummy string as mentioned here: : https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-hyperlocal. My basic idea is to decrypt a hyperlocal string as described here but even the Google code is running me into circles.

Comment: As asked before, could you show the output of Google and - if possible - some plain text data to compare it with?

Comment: I'm sending this string: private static final byte[] long_ciphertext = hexStringToByteArray("E2014EA201246E6F6E636520736F7572636501414243C0ADF6B9B6AC17DA218FB50331EDB376701309CAAA01246E6F6E636520736F7572636501414243C09ED4ECF2DB7143A9341FDEFD125D96844E25C3C202466E6F6E636520736F7572636502414243517C16BAFADCFAB841DE3A8C617B2F20A1FB7F9EA3A3600256D68151C093C793B0116DB3D0B8BE9709304134EC9235A026844F276797"); and I should be getting back this after decryption: encrypted_hyperlocal_set:(
    {  100,  100 },
    {  200, -300 },
    { -400,  500 },
    { -600, -700 },)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/response-guide/decrypt-hyperlocal#decryption

Comment: Instead I get:�qT����p�R����<��h�7�$�Ci��,H�}�x����K�:&쯄��lk'<��zN?�垒}��i�AsX�S����\b�x��vV'P���!~K�W�h��@g٫Mim5ŗ�P����g-+S�m�l��Hϯc��ՠ�&Qx'{\\5\f��>�\tP\nvd�q;P�b�<��d_�e���)�F�&�MWn�Sd�~Jz_�4�Ƕ�Fp5��7u��ӴM����v$��3��g�fq��

Comment: Again, never print as text, please, as hex. And put it in the question not in a comment as it gets unreadable.

Comment: OK, I give up, either algorithm is wrong, keys or ciphertext is not valid or I cannot program a damn :)

Answer (score -1):

I contacted to Google to find out why. The answer is that the document is wrong.
The provided 154-byte code is not encrypted to hyperlocal set, it's encrypted to bid request set.
I successfully decoded the hyperlocal set.

1. Decrypt from hexadecimal to Binary data.
2. Decrypt from Binary Data to Bid Request Set, using Bid Request Protocol buffer and get each idfa, hyperlocal Set and other set.
3. Decrypt from Hyperlocal Set(Binary Data) to Hyperlocal decryption using hyperlocal protocol buffer.

Please see my github( however python and php )
https://github.com/kay-si/Google_AdEx_Decrypt/blob/master/python/sample/hyperlocal.py

Comment: It would be better if you explained in detail in the answer how you did the fix rather than linking to an external site, as external links can eventually break and render the answer no longer useful.